# react-native - *.js importing *.ts file

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

How to allow `*.js` files to import `*.ts` files in `react-native` but **without rename of any of two files**?

we want to import below `src/lib/setGlobalStyle`**.ts** file from the `src/App`**.js**

```
//MIT LICENSE from: https://github.com/Ajackster/react-native-global-props

import React from 'react'
import { StyleProp, ViewStyle } from 'react-native'


export function setGlobalStyle(obj, customProps) {
 const oldRender = obj.prototype.render;
  const initialDefaultProps = obj.prototype.constructor.defaultProps;
  obj.prototype.constructor.defaultProps = {
    ...initialDefaultProps,
    ...customProps,
  }
  obj.prototype.render = function render() {
    let oldProps = this.props;
    this.props = { ...this.props, style: [customProps.style, this.props.style] };
    try {
      return oldRender.apply(this, arguments);
    } finally {
      this.props = oldProps;
    }
  };
}
```

but below import which is inside `App`**.js** only works when we rename the `setGlobalStyle`**.ts** file to `setGlobalStyle`**.js**:

```
import * as Utils from './lib/setGlobalStyle'
```

and of course the `setGlobalStyle`**.ts** currently does not contain any `TypeScript` types, that is because we had to remove all and rename it to **.js** so we can continue on the project until this gets an answer.

**note**: the reason why we need `TypeScript` is to allow `IDE` autocomplete of the parameters (i.e. the `customProps` argument).

Comment: Do you have any particular IDE in mind?

Comment: Although this is not `IDE` related and would get the same by using `CLI` with a raw text editor the `IDE` of choice is `VS Code` @ippi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSDoc-support in Javascript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JSDoc-support-in-JavaScript) allows you to import type definitions directly. I know that's not the same as importing the actual module (but I think that is madness if the type definitions exist):

```
/**
 * @param {import("./mymodule").customProps } customProps
 */
export function setGlobalStyle(obj, customProps) {
    customProps. // has full auto-completion
```

[image]

Comment: And if the module itself is in JS we can create `types.d.ts` file with content like `export type MyType = {};`, then use it the same way where required: ```/** @param {import('../types').MyType} myParamName */```